# How to get store value from another store?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

How to get store value from another store?
https://svelte.dev/repl/0ab80c2fb8e045958d844bd4b11c04a9?version=3.22.1

In the example I include a variable `inputVal` in `stores.js` file and changing in
`set: (val) => {inputVal=val; set( val );}, and use in fn setToZero`

Question: how to do it directly without using the `inputVal` variable?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `get(store)` to access a stores value.

Example:

```js
import {get, writable} from 'svelte/store'

const myStore = writable(41)

const value = get(myStore)
```

If you are accessing a store from within a `.svelte` component, there is a shortcut. Just prefix the store name with `$`, eg. `const value = $myStore`.

Comment: Minus of this solution:  "This works by creating a subscription, reading the value, then unsubscribing. It's therefore not recommended in hot code paths."  https://svelte.dev/docs#get

Comment: Alternatives: 1) Use `store.subscribe(callback)`, the callback will be notified when the value changes. 2) Use a derived store `derived([storeA, storeB, ...], callback)`, when any dependent stores change your callback can produce a new (aggregate) value

Comment: @lukaszpolowczyk's link is now https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-get